# How are word files formatted?

Tags: tags, formatting, ms-word

Are word files formatted like HTML - that is, does it have a tag-based form behind the displayed tables, forms, etc.? If not, how is it done, and how can I, for example, create a code that will insert a word-formatted table on clipboard?

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: I have tried searching on google for several terms but all I have found is formatting tips.

Comment: MS at its finest with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Comment: Closed as 'NOT A REAL QUESTION'!?

Comment: @Dokkat: yeah, I don't get that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any .docx word document can be converted to XML.  Just do a Save as to the document and choose XML word document.  It will save as a file you can open in Notepad and see the XML tagging, and then you just need to take the time to hash thru it to get the proper XML format (try an XML Reader).

Comment: I should've thought in converting it, doh! Great. Thank you very much.